# Assign a Google Apps Script function to a Google Sheets image with code

Tags: image, button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

ASSIGN a GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT FUNCTION TO an IMAGE WITH CODE.

By clicking on a image in a Google Sheet and selecting the "Assign Script" option, it is possible.

[image: Assign Script to Image]

But this is a manual task and I want to automate this.

Comment: Not sure exactly what it is you are looking for- Have you looked at the project triggers? This can automate tasks.

Comment: If the images are placed on sidebars or dialogs which are generated with the html service then you can assign onClick events to them and [run any server side google apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: A new feature was released October 30, 2018. See [release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2018#october_30_2018) that now allows a script to be assigned to an image with code.  See new answer.

Answer (score 2):

An image can be inserted into a Google Sheet and assigned a function with Apps Script code.

There is an `insertImage()` method for the Sheet Class and an `assignScript()` method that can be run on an image.

The `insertImage()` method requires a blob of an image mime type.  To get an image of a jpeg mime type, you can draw and image, save it to a local drive, upload the image to your Google Drive, and then with code, get the image as a blob.

### Steps to create an image, get it as a blob, insert into sheet and assign a function

- In a Google Sheet click "Insert" and then "Drawing"
- Draw an image - For example an image that looks like a button
- Save the image to your computer drive
- From Google Drive, click "New" and "File Upload" and upload the image file to your Google Drive and give it a name
- Get the image file in code as shown in the test function below
- Convert the image file to a blob in code
- Run the code to insert the image and assign a function

**Code example:**

Note that the image doesn't show up until after the browser tab with the spreadsheet have been refreshed.

```
function setImage(po) {
try{
  var image,sh,ss;

  /*
    po.blobSource - a blob that is an image file type
    po.column - the column to set the image in
    po.functionName - the name of the function to assign to the image
    po.row - the row to set the image in
    po.shName - the name of the sheet tab
  */

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//This code is bound to a Sheet
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(po.shName);
  image = sh.insertImage(po.blobSource, po.column, po.row);//Insert an image and return the image

  image.assignScript(po.functionName);//Assign an Apps Script function to the image

  return true;
}catch(e){
  //Logger.log('Error: ' + e.message)
  //Logger.log('stack: ' + e.stack)
  return false;
}
}

function testRun() {
  var blobSrc,contentType,file,files;

  /*
    In a Sheet click Insert and Drawing
    Draw a button
    Save the button to your computer drive
    From Google Drive click "New" and File Upload and upload the file and give it a name
    Get the image file in code as shown in this function
    Convert the image file to a blob
  */

  files = DriveApp.searchFiles('mimeType contains "jpeg" and title contains "Name of File Here"');
  if (files.hasNext()) {
   file = files.next();
  }

  contentType = 'image/jpeg';

  if (file) {
    blobSrc = file.getAs(contentType);
  }

  //Logger.log(blobSrc.getContentType());  

  //Logger.log(blobSrc.getName())
  setImage({shName:'Sheet1',blobSource:blobSrc,row:1,column:1,functionName:'myFunction'});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this recently, here's a snippet of programmatically adding the image and linking the function to it. My image is hosted in Google Drive so I use the file ID, otherwise you can replace that with an image URL

Replace the 1's with your col/row index that you'd like the image to start in and you can add another 2 optional parameters around ofsetting the X and Y axis too. Looks at this page and scroll down to the various insertImage options: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

Example:

```
function insertImage() {

let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let s = ss.getSheetByName("**SHEETNAMEHERE**") // you can also use ID or other methods to grab the sheet

s.insertImage(DriveApp.getFileById("1s64XKA88mbLwl-qEBhSMB7EQFW1y0-Dl"), 1, 1)
  .assignScript("#functionName#");
 // you can also replace "DriveApp.getFileById("#ID#")" with "#Image URL#" if it's not in Drive
}
```