# Assign function to hyperlink image with Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script creates an image in a cell using this hyperlink function

```
=HYPERLINK("http://example.com", IMAGE("http://example.com/myimage.png", 1))

function search() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var bd = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('base_de_donnees'), true);
  var fiche = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('fiches_locataires'), true);
  var nameSearch = fiche.getRange("R9:S10").getValue();

  var nameResults = []
  var data = bd.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lenght = 0
  data.forEach(function (row) {
    if(row[9] == nameSearch){
      lenght = lenght + 1
      nameResults.push(row);
    } 
 });

 var search = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('recherche'), true);
 for(i=0; i < lenght; i++){
    search.getRange("A" + (i+1) + ":BT" + (i+1)).setValues([nameResults[i], =HYPERLINK("http://example.com", IMAGE("http://example.com/myimage.png", 1))]) // Write an array to range and last column = image
 }

}
```

I also have this function

```
function see_file(){
    create a file
}
```

Is it possible to assign a Google script function to this cell (column with the image) or to the image ?

```
function add_script_to_cell(){
    add the function see_file() to a cell/image
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Short answer, no. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Sorry. Hopefully my edits will help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to assign a script to an image returned by a formula, this is only possible to images that are inserted "over the grid".

Resources

- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [assingScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#assignscriptfunctionname)

Related

- [Assign a Google Apps Script function to a Google Sheets image with code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43229075/1595451)
- [Google Script: Attach a script to a dynamically added image in a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64670496/1595451)